# Https Icon is getting changed for website which has SSL certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have site which has SSL certificate and as i am navigating the page my lock icon which shows before the https is getiing chaged.

[image: As shown in the screenshot i am not getting the lock icon before the https]

As shown in the screenshot i am not getting the lock icon before the https.
I have checked the certificate and certificate is all right.I am not understanding why this is happening. Is this is a issue or not.

Please help me for the same.

Thank you for the same in advance

Comment: If the browser is chrome, you have ressources on your page which still load stuff using http...

Comment: Did you try clicking on the icon?

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening if you are referencing CSS OR JS from third party location using HTTP in your page.